# Equivalent of R's tapply() in Python Pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, tapply

I have a dataset that contains the feeding data of 3 animals, consisting of the animals' tag ids (1,2,3), the type (A,B) and amount (kg) of feed given at each 'meal':

```
Animal   FeedType   Amount(kg)
Animal1     A         10
Animal2     B         7
Animal3     A         4
Animal2     A         2
Animal1     B         5
Animal2     B         6
Animal3     A         2
```

In base R, I can easily output the matrix below which has `unique('Animal')` as its rows, `unique('FeedType')` as its columns and the cumulative `Amount (kg)` in the corresponding cells of the matrix by using `tapply()` as below

```
out <- with(mydf, tapply(Amount, list(Animal, FeedType), sum))

         A  B
Animal1 10  5
Animal2  2 13
Animal3  6 NA
```

Is there an equivalent functionality for a Python Pandas dataframe? What is the most elegant and fastest way to achieve this in Pandas?

P.S. I want to be able to specify on what column, in this case `Amount`, to perform the aggregation.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I tried both approaches in the two answers. Performance results with my actual Pandas data-frame of 216,347 rows and 15 columns:

```
start_time1 = timeit.default_timer()
mydf.groupby(['Animal','FeedType'])['Amount'].sum()
elapsed_groupby = timeit.default_timer() - start_time1

start_time2 = timeit.default_timer()
mydf.pivot_table(rows='Animal', cols='FeedType',values='Amount',aggfunc='sum')
elapsed_pivot = timeit.default_timer() - start_time2

print ('elapsed_groupby: ' + str(elapsed_groupby))
print ('elapsed_pivot: ' + str(elapsed_pivot))
```

gives:

```
elapsed_groupby: 10.172213
elapsed_pivot: 8.465783
```

**So in my case, pivot_table() works faster.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach of @Zelazny7 with `groupby` and `unstack` is certainly fine, but for completeness, you can also do this directly with `pivot_table` (see [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table)) [version 0.13 and below]:

```
In [13]: df.pivot_table(rows='Animal', cols='FeedType', values='Amount(kg)', aggfunc='sum')
Out[13]:
FeedType   A   B
Animal
Animal1   10   5
Animal2    2  13
Animal3    6 NaN
```

In newer versions of Pandas (version 0.14 and latter), arguments of pivot_table have been changed:

```
In [13]: df.pivot_table(index='Animal', columns='FeedType', values='Amount(kg)', aggfunc='sum')
Out[13]:
FeedType   A   B
Animal
Animal1   10   5
Animal2    2  13
Animal3    6 NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, Is this faster than `groupBy()`? I could not figure out how to specify the `Amount` column in the `groupBy()` approach. I sense that grouping by the entire data frame is unnecessary and may pose performance issues. I want to specifically use `df$Amount` while aggregating.

Comment: Some quick `timeit` results show the groupby approach to be slightly faster (2.44ms versus 3.28ms with 100 loops)

Comment: @Zelazny7, I tested both approaches using `timeit` as you suggested. `pivot_table()` was faster in my case as I added to my question. But I am grateful for your answer anyways.

Comment: @Zhubarb If you are using IPython, for timings I find it easier to use `%timeit` (eg `%timeit mydf.groupby(['Animal','FeedType'])['Amount'].sum()`)

Answer (score 7):

First I read in your data:

```
In [7]: df = pd.read_clipboard(sep="\s+", index_col=False)

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
    Animal FeedType  Amount(kg)
0  Animal1        A          10
1  Animal2        B           7
2  Animal3        A           4
3  Animal2        A           2
4  Animal1        B           5
5  Animal2        B           6
6  Animal3        A           2
```

Then I can groupby the two columns to aggregate:

```
In [9]: df.groupby(['Animal','FeedType']).sum()
Out[9]:
                  Amount(kg)
Animal  FeedType
Animal1 A                 10
        B                  5
Animal2 A                  2
        B                 13
Animal3 A                  6
```

To get it in the same format, I can `unstack` the `dataframe`:

```
In [10]: df.groupby(['Animal','FeedType']).sum().unstack()
Out[10]:
          Amount(kg)
FeedType           A   B
Animal
Animal1           10   5
Animal2            2  13
Animal3            6 NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can I specify: `df.groupby(['Animal','FeedType']).sum()` to sum over `'Amount'` specifically? I have other float columns in the same dataframe and I am only interested in the `'Amount'` values.

Comment: Do `df.groupby(['Animal','FeedType'])['Amount'].sum()`

Comment: Yes, sorry I figured this out after I wrote my comment. But does that mean I am grouping by all columns that are not in ['Animal', 'FeedType'] in the first place? I did not specify this in my question to keep it brief and to the point but I indeed have many columns and would like to limit the operation to a single column if possible.